# Please help me debug the error:java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Iam trying to pass a user input value from one activity to another. In the second activity Iam doing some manipulation on the data and displaying the final value. But it is giving a nullpointerexception.

What is the error in my code?

first activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fourth);

    final EditText et;
    final Button b;

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
{
               Intent intent = new Intent(Fourth.this, Fifth.class);
               intent.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());
               startActivity(intent);

            Intent intentnew = new Intent(Fourth.this, Sixth.class);
            intentnew.putExtra("thetext", et.getText().toString());            
            startActivity(intentnew);   

}
```

next activity where the data is received and displayed.(the code snippet)

```
TextView tvr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.finalremark);


double wto=Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("the text"));

                            double z=wto*0.75;

                            String weight= Double.toString(z); 

                            tvr.setText(weight);
```

the logcat

```
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at    com.example.footforthought.Sixth$2.handleMessage(Sixth.java:380)
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at  android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
09-03 11:11:06.069: E/AndroidRuntime(30262):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-03 11:11:17.969: I/Process(30262): Sending signal. PID: 30262 SIG: 9
```

Comment: And mark the line where your NPE comes from.

Comment: You start two activities at the same time. WHY?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'thetext'..you have added spaces in between..remove the space

```
double wto=Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext"));//here remove the space in name 'thetext'

                            double z=wto*0.75;

                            String weight= Double.toString(z); 

                            tvr.setText(weight);
```

Comment: And I would defensively add a check for `getString()` returning `null` before passing it on to `parseDouble`.

Answer (score 2):

You are giving wrong key value while retrieving the data.
While saving the key value pair, notice the key -

intent.putExtra("**thetext**", et.getText().toString());

While retrieving the key value pair, notice the key (There is an extra space.)

double wto=Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("**the text**"));

Change the above line to

```
double wto=Double.parseDouble(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext"));
```

and it should work fine.